# Composer Update Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

A developer has sent me his project to work with, but when ever I try to update or install my vendors everything works great until the very end and it outputs the message bellow.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\BigWaveMedia\davinkit>php artisan migrate
{
    "error": {
        "type": "Exception",
        "message": "expected color value: failed at `.clearfix;` C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\BigWaveMedia\\davinkit\\app\\start\/..\/..\/public\/less\/style.less on line 102",
        "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\davinkit\\vendor\\leafo\\lessphp\\lessc.inc.php",
        "line": 3258
    }
}
C:\xampp\htdocs\BigWaveMedia\davinkit>
```

Any ideas at all? Here is a full log http://pastebin.com/y9q4Rc5z

Comment: Show your `composer.json` too.

Comment: It's trying to compile LESS... fix the error with color on line 102 of the `style.less` file?

Comment: @DavidBarker I think you're right, but why is it doing that during a migration? What was that other developer doing?

Comment: Im not sure I can even get this to composer install?

Comment: Also, I gave up on using any of the PHP LESS compilers because they are sometimes not quite up to date and can have trouble compiling things like Bootstrap. Thus, the problem may not be with the `style.less` file, it could be the compiler.

Comment: I agree, PHP run time LESS/SASS compilers are terrible unless they're kept up to date / actually work in the first place. @Brent I suspect the other developer wanted to display how great he was by using a run time LESS compiler. Just strip it out, comment out the service provider and make a note to the other dev what you've done to get it working.

Comment: Please share more details. How is this question related to Composer? `php artisan migrate` doesn't call that?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

When you run `composer update`, `composer` generates a file called `composer.lock` which lists all your packages and the currently installed versions. This allows you to later run `composer install`, which will install the packages listed in that file, recreating the environment that you were last using.

It appears from your log that some of the versions of packages that are listed in your `composer.lock` file are no longer available. Thus, when you run `composer install`, it complains and fails. This is usually no big deal - just run `composer update` and it will attempt to build a set of packages that work together and write a new `composer.lock` file.

However, you're running into a different problem. It appears that, in your `composer.json` file, the original developer has added some pre- or post- update actions that are failing, specifically a `php artisan migrate` command. This can be avoided by running the following:     `composer update --no-scripts`

This will run the composer update but will skip over the scripts added to the file. You should be able to successfully run the update this way.

However, this does not solve the problem long-term. There are two problems:

1. A migration is for database changes, not random stuff like compiling assets. Go through the migrations and remove that code from there.
2. Assets should not be compiled each time you run `composer update`. Remove that step from the `composer.json` file.

From what I've read, best practice seems to be compiling assets on an as-needed basis during development (ie. when you're making changes to your LESS files - ideally using a tool like [gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/)) and before deployment.

Comment: **TL;DR**  `composer update --no-scripts` +1 & thanks

Answer (score 32):

The following works for me:

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

Answer (score 1):

this is command for composer update please try this...

composer self-update

Comment: Can you explain why that should be neccessary?

Answer (score -1):

write this command in your terminal :

> composer update

Comment: Why? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. The OP already wrote that `composer update` triggers the error, so I doubt that running it again magically resolves the problem

Comment: This is what I did to update my laravel dependencies after cloning it from Github. I navigated to the application directory and ran composer update from the terminal.

Answer (score -2):

You can use :

```
composer self-update --2
```

To update to 2.0.8 version (Latest stable version)

Comment: Please share more details. How does this relate to the given question? Why should updating Composer resolve the problem?