# Class excel does not exist in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, excel, laravel-5

I am trying to download excel in laravel 5.2. But server is given this error

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 734:   Class excel does not
>   exist

**this work  fine in localhost**

this my **function**

```
 return Excel::create('users', function($excel) use($datas) {
            return   $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) use($datas) {

                $datasheet = array();
                $datasheet[0]  =   array('id','Voucher No','Code','Expiry Date','Created_at');
                $i=1;
                foreach($datas as $datanew){
                    $datasheet[$i] = array( @$datanew['id'],
                        $datanew['vouchers_no'],
                        $datanew['code'],
                        $datanew['date'],
                        $datanew['created_at'],
                    );
                    $i++;
                }
                $sheet->fromArray($datasheet);

            });

        })->download('xlsx');
```

used packegeis

> maatwebsite/excel

i am add this two line in **config/app.php**

```
Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
```

it work fine in localhost but showing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a similar behavior in my production server.
Resolved by executing:

```
composer update
composer update --no-scripts
```

The first to update all objects ;
the other to avoid the scripts execution that can be failed during update

Comment: Yep like me. It's working fine in localhost. But not in the production server. You can find some explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782960/composer-update-laravel

Answer (score 1):

For me, this issue comes on **GoDaddy** server when I created a zip file of the **vendor** folder in **laravel** and replaced it with the server as I included new packages there. Nothing worked as **ssh terminal** was not enabled by the client for the final solution I deleted the files inside `bootstrap/cache` and it worked perfectly.